# Create a file locally on android(not on SD card)

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, io

I am having an issue where I am trying to create a file locally on the android emulator however when I test it the file exists, it doesn't. I do not have access to a physical android device so am using the emulator.
Please note I do not want to save the file on the SD card. I am not very familiar with android's file structure so forgive me if my code doesn't make sense.
This is the code I am currently using and it doesn't work :(

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        String  sName = editText.getText().toString();

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        String  sEmail = editText.getText().toString();

        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPostal);
        String  sPostal = editText.getText().toString();

File file = new File("/storage/new/test.txt");
        FileOutputStream fos;
        byte[] data = new String("Name: " + sName + " Subject: " + sEmail + " Question: " + sPostal ).getBytes();

        OutputStream myOutput;
            try {
            myOutput = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file,true));
            myOutput.write(data);
            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        if(file.exists())
        {
            finish();
        }
```

Could anyone experienced enough in the area of android development provide me with some sample code or point me in the right direction so I can get this bad boy working? 
**EDIT:** When I say it doesn't work, I mean the file never gets created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are new to file storage in Android I suggest you read trough [this piece of documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) to get started - it should answer your questions with examples.

Comment: thanks for your reply. The code under "Using the Internal Storage" seems like it might work. Does that allow me to refer to the file using its name (in this case "hello_file") so I can do something with the file at a later stage?

Comment: If you mean access the file as if it was in your project resources, no. You should always access it via its path.